# How can i call two different functions when the document is loaded for the first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with different inputs and i have some functions to alter the inputs values.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

   jQuery('.cx-ui-container input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(e){
    
     slug_and_hide(jQuery(this));
   })

  jQuery('.cx-ui-container select').on('change', function(e){
      handle_select_change(jQuery(this));
   })
```

The following function hides or shows a textarea field depending on the value of the select field:

```
   function handle_select_change(obj) {
        var selectField = jQuery(obj);
        var selectedValue = selectField.val();
        var textareaField = obj.parents('.cheryr-ui-repeater-content-box').find('textarea');
        console.log(textareaField);
        console.log(selectedValue);

        if (selectedValue !== "multiple-choice") {
            textareaField.css("display", "none");
        } else {
            textareaField.val(""); 
            textareaField.css("display", "block");
        }   
    }
```

The following function creates a slug from the value inputed in the previous input field:

```
    function slug_and_hide(obj){

        var inputField = jQuery(obj).val();
        
        //Pass Label to lower case and replace spaces with dashes
        let slug = inputField.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');

        //Replace special characters except dashes and alphanumeric characters
        slug = slug.replace(/[^a-z0-9-]/g, '');

        //Remove leading and trailing dashes
        slug = slug.replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '');

        

        let inputSlug = jQuery(obj).parents('.cheryr-ui-repeater-content-box').find('.input-slug-wrap').find('input');
        console.log(inputSlug, slug);
        inputSlug.prop('readonly', true);
        inputSlug.val(slug);
        inputSlug.css("display", "block");

    }
}
```

I have the following issue. Both of my functions work but not at first.
So the select has 3 options: `Stars`, `Multiple-Choice` and `Yes/No`. The textarea field should be shown only if the value of the select is `Multiple-Choice`. The issue is that as the page loads for the first time, the textarea field is shown no matter what the value of the select is. And the function is triggered after the value is changed for the first time. How can i make for my function to be triggered for the first time the page is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options.

One is simple pass the element's selector directly to the jquery function.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

   jQuery('.cx-ui-container input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(e){
     slug_and_hide(jQuery(this));
   })

  jQuery('.cx-ui-container select').on('change', function(e){
      handle_select_change(jQuery(this));
   })

     slug_and_hide(jQuery('.cx-ui-container input[type="text"]'));
      handle_select_change(jQuery('.cx-ui-container select'));
})
```

But the textarea might still show briefly depending on page load.

Another option is toggle a class that hides/shows the elements instead of using javascript to change the display. Then add that class to the elements you want hidden.

**.hide{display:none;}**

**textareaField.classList.toggle("hide")**

and

**inputSlug.classList.toggle("hide")**